# django filter if object appears in another table

Tags: django

I have a model `Device` and a model `BrokenSensor`. In the `BrokenSensor` table, all the devices with broken sensor get a row.

The `BrokenSensor` model looks like this:

```
class BrokenSensor(models.Model):
    sensor = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=Sensor.choices())
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="brokensensor"
    )

    def __str__(self):  # pragma: no cover
        return "pk{} - device: {} - sensor: {}".format(
            self.pk, self.device_id, self.sensor
        )
```

How can I do the most efficient way this query:

Give me all the devices, except the devices the `BrokenSensor` table

Comment: As an aside, the related_name should be `broken_sensors` or similar, since there may be several `BrokenSensor` s per device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with the `brokensensor` being `None` in the related model:

```
Device.objects.filter(brokensensor=None)
```

This works since Django makes a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so if there is no `BrokenSensor`, it will include a row with `NULL`, and we filter on that one.

As [@AKX says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62152166/django-filter-if-object-appears-in-another-table/62152286#comment109922426_62152166) however, the reverse of a `ForeignKey` is plural, since multiple `BrokenSensor`s can point to the same device, you thus might want to rename it to:

```
class BrokenSensor(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(
        Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='broken_sensors'
    )
    # …
```

then the query is:

```
Device.objects.filter(broken_sensors=None)
```